# Print contents of a list with along with nested list in one column in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to this and logic of loops still troubles me.
I have failed to find my answer, trying to print a list contents along with another nested list all in a one column (python 3.6)

```
List1=['123','1234',[12345,54321],'321']

for item in List1:
    for i in item:
        print(i,end=' ')
    print
```

so far I get output of list vertically char by char and nested list horizontally in one line.

also if 123 is a int without `''` it return me an error msg int not iterable.

Comment: What is your real question? The data you have is a list with strings and one of these elements is a list with integers. Where did you get that data from?

Comment: if my answer actually solves your problem i expect you to upvote and mark it as answered. thank you

Comment: downvoted the question due to unreasonable downvote of solving answer.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand what you want exactly, but these can help:

If you want each item of List1 in seperate lines:

```
for item in List1:
    if type(item) == list:
        for i in item:
            print(i, end=' ')
    else:
        print(item, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
123
1234
12345 54321
321
```

If you want all items(nesteds included) in one column:

```
for item in List1:
    if type(item) == list:
        for i in item:
            print(i)
    else:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
123
1234
12345
54321
321
```

Comment: if someone asks a python question, they should get it the pythonic way. list comprehensions rather then nested "for" loops. "join"-function, rather than print() for a new-line.

Comment: @EvilSmurf  I was just trying not to confuse OP. He used for loops. He does not asking for a pythonic way, just wants to understand **logic of loops**. Read the question again.

Comment: well, mentioning "python 3.6" several times (headline, question) was a pointer for me to direct him to python. the logic of loops wasn't explained in your response either, where one could have mentioned that for python it doesn't matter whether its for item in list or for letter in string. it would take one or the other based on the type of the iterable. the error comes, since an integer is not something that can be iterrated over, in python

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I'll try to get it in list comprehebnsion now to save some unnecessary lines of code. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, now I don't need to explain more to others.

Comment: however it still returns an error if list contents is a mixture of  int and str ...

Comment: Your example list is a mixture of int and str. It works with your example list. Can you share the list which causes this error.

Comment: Alperen My bad I've found an error in my list, it works indeed for mixed lists. Thanks a lot! it saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

```
print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in List1]))
```

"print[s] a list contents along with another nested list all in a one column" - as requested

```
print('\n'.join([str(i) if type(i) != list else '\n'.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in List1]))
```

to use to even split the nested list on a new line for each element (only works for 1 level nesting). you would have to write a recursive function to make it work for a nesting of *n*

Comment: The second option is what I wanted however this list comprehension looks super complicated and long

Comment: well to explain: join - joins item in a list by the given string. the lists inside are created to make sure the items are converted to string (in case they are integers, like in your example) - A downvote is not acceptable for a solution that solves your problem, just because your understanding is limited. I am really sorry